# AWS - Automatic remediation of EC2s with Public IP

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Looking develop a python script that will scan EC2 instances for Public IP's and if found, stop those instances.

I'm sorta new to Python so have challenges trying to put two pieces of code together.

```
ec2Resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        instances = ec2Resource.instances.all()
        for instance in instances:
            #print("inst.public_ip_address",inst.public_ip_address)
            if instance.public_ip_address:
                print("Instance ID: ",instance.id," , Instance Platform: ",instance.platform," , Public IP: ",instance.public_ip_address,", Instance Type:",instance.instance_type,",Instance Image Id: ",instance.image.id) 
response = client.stop_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    Hibernate=True,
    DryRun=False,
    Force=False
)
```

Basically, looking for a automated script that discovers public IPs on EC2's and then stops them. My apologies if the script above looks hamburglar

UPDATE:
Think I cleaned it up to create lists and then from that list, issue a stop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
'''
    Finds instance id, Instance Platform, Public IP, instance type based on tags.
    Returns a list of instances found
'''

import boto3

def instances_find(name, value):
    '''
    Finds instance id's based on tags.
    Returns a list of instances found.
    '''
    list_instances = []
    # filter based on tags
    filters =[
        {
        'Name': name,
        'Values': [
            value,
            ]
        },
    ]
    instances = ec2_resource.instances.filter(Filters=filters)
    for instance in instances:
        # for each instance, append to list
        list_instances.append("Instance ID: ",instance.id," , Instance Platform: ",instance.platform," , Public IP: ",instance.public_ip_address,", Instance Type:",instance.instance_type,",Instance Image Id: ",instance.image.id)
    return list_instances

def instances_stop(list):
    '''
    Stops instances defined in the list.
    '''
    ec2_client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=list)

# enter tag name and value
tag_name = 'tag:environment'
tag_value = 'dev'

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

# find instances
ec2_list = instances_find(tag_name, tag_value)
# stop instances
ec2_stop = instances_stop(ec2_list)
print('stopped instances: ' + str(ec2_list))
```

Comment: Rather than giving us all of your code, could you please narrow-down your question to a specific issue you are having? For example, are you successfully getting a list of desired instances? If so, are you successfully stopping that list of instances? People probably aren't going to read through all your code to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Thank you John.  First time user :)  I'll follow that logic to my next Stack post.

Comment: If you'd like some assistance with _this_ question, feel free to edit the question to highlight the specific situation you'd like us to assist with.